# Limit the record count that an array pulls in Visual Foxpro

Tags: visual-foxpro

How do you limit the record count that an array gets populated with?

TMI - I have a folder with thousands of records.  I want to move them out of the "main" folder and move them into folders of the YYYYMMDD that they were created.  I need to do this in small sections instead of one massive pull of data.

Comment: based on when CREATED? or last Modified date... typically the same for static documents... and why not just let the whole thing get processed by VFP in a single run.  I would think it might take only a few seconds (less than a minute) to move them to respective subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of folders like so: Adir(MyArray,"*.*","D",1)

Then add the array to a cursor: CREATE CURSOR myFolders (MyFoldername C(100))

Then perform your batch function for every X rows in the cursor, etc...